# Alignment issue of UIElements in iOS 7

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, xcode6

I have written a UITableView cell in Code.

```
override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) 
{

super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        var yPos : CGFloat = 10.0

        let collectionFrame = CGRectMake(0, yPos, Constants.DimentionKeys.kDeviceWidth, Constants.DimentionKeys.kDeviceWidth)
        var layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirection.Horizontal
        layout.itemSize = CGSizeMake(Constants.DimentionKeys.kDeviceWidth, Constants.DimentionKeys.kDeviceWidth)
        layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
        layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
        layout.minimumLineSpacing = 0

        self.ImageCollectionView = UICollectionView(frame: collectionFrame, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        self.ImageCollectionView!.registerClass(CollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "CollectionViewCell")
        self.ImageCollectionView?.tag = 11
        self.ImageCollectionView?.pagingEnabled = true
        self.ImageCollectionView?.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 242/255.0, green: 237/255.0, blue: 235/255.0, alpha: 1.0)

        self.contentView.addSubview(self.ImageCollectionView!)



        self.ShareBtn.frame = CGRectMake(10.0, yPos, 35.0, 35.0)
        self.ShareBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "share"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        self.contentView.addSubview(self.ShareBtn)

        yPos += collectionFrame.height

        self.offerLbl.frame = CGRectMake(10.0, yPos, Constants.DimentionKeys.kDeviceWidth - 20.0, 30.0)
        self.offerLbl.numberOfLines = 3
        self.offerLbl.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
        self.offerLbl.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica Neue", size: 12.0)
        self.offerLbl.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 213/255.0, green: 221/255.0, blue: 234/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
        self.contentView.addSubview(self.offerLbl)

        yPos += 45.0

        self.priceLbl.frame = CGRectMake(10.0, yPos, self.offerLbl.frame.size.width - 35.0, 35.0)
        self.priceLbl.font = UIFont(name: "Verdana", size: 21.0)
        self.contentView.addSubview(self.priceLbl)

        self.wishListBtn.frame = CGRectMake(self.priceLbl.frame.size.width + 10.0, yPos, 35.0, 35.0)
        self.wishListBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "wishlist"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        self.contentView.addSubview(self.wishListBtn)

        yPos += 40.0

        self.splPriceLbl.frame = CGRectMake(10.0, yPos, self.priceLbl.frame.width, 20.0)
        self.splPriceLbl.font = UIFont(name: "Verdana", size: 14.0)
        self.splPriceLbl.textColor = UIColor.redColor()
        self.contentView.addSubview(self.splPriceLbl)

        yPos += 25.0


        self.productNameLbl.frame = CGRectMake(10.0, yPos, self.frame.width - 20.0, 20.0)
        self.productNameLbl.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica Neue", size: 16.0)
        self.contentView.addSubview(self.productNameLbl)

        yPos += 22.0

        self.productDescLbl.frame = CGRectMake(10.0, yPos, self.frame.width - 20.0, 40.0)
        self.productDescLbl.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica Neue", size: 13.0)
        self.productDescLbl.numberOfLines = 5
        self.contentView.addSubview(self.productDescLbl)

        yPos += 45.0


        self.variantSelectorBtn.frame = CGRectMake(10.0, yPos, (Constants.DimentionKeys.kDeviceWidth / 2.0 - 20.0 ), 35.0)
        self.variantSelectorBtn.setTitle("Customise this product", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        self.variantSelectorBtn.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(12.0)
        self.variantSelectorBtn.setTitleColor(UIColor.blackColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        self.variantSelectorBtn.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
        self.variantSelectorBtn.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
        self.contentView.addSubview(self.variantSelectorBtn)


        self.TBtn.frame = CGRectMake(Constants.DimentionKeys.kDeviceWidth / 2.0 + 20.0, yPos, Constants.DimentionKeys.kDeviceWidth / 2.0 - 40.0, 35.0)
        self.TBtn.setAttributedTitle(Product.getTwoColorString("Free Try"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        self.TBtn.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(12.0)
        self.TBtn.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
        self.TBtn.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
        self.contentView.addSubview(self.TBtn)

        yPos += 35.0

    }
```

All the UIElemens in that UITableView Cell has moved left while executing. Even for the UIElements which has X-position as Zero(Some part of that UIElement moved out of the screen to the Left).This happens in iOS 7 alone. The application i'm working with supports from iOS 7 to iOS 8.3 and it is a Universal application.

Comment: Do you use storyboards or xib file?

Comment: I use storyboard in that storyboard i'm using a custom tableViewCell which is written in code

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have to check the autoresizing values of the cell and its content.

1)Go to the storyboard.

2)Select the cell

3)Go to Size Inspector tab

4)Try to modify autoresizing values for its content

Comment: Hi, Actually I have written the tableViewCell in code but the tableView is in storyboard.

Comment: How can i apply your solution for a tableViewCell which is written in code. Do you know any other solution which will fix my problem

Comment: You can "play" with the autoresizingMask of each element of your tableView. Also you have to check the documentation here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/autoresizingMask